# Dijkstra and FileInput. Java

Tags: java, file, dijkstra

I have this Dijkstra algorithm java code below. I downloaded the code. I want to make changes to this program and store the data in file and read it in rather than put it in the source code. What would be the best ways to do this?

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
public final String name;
public Edge[] adjacencies;
public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
public Vertex previous;

public Vertex(String argName) { 
    name = argName;
}

public String toString() {
    return name;
}


public int compareTo(Vertex other)
{
    return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
}

}


class Edge
{
public final Vertex target;
public final double weight;

public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) { 

    target = argTarget; 
    weight = argWeight; 
}
}


public class Dijkstra
{
public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
{
    source.minDistance = 0.;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
        {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double weight = e.weight;
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
    if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
        vertexQueue.remove(v);

        v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
        v.previous = u;
        vertexQueue.add(v);

    }

        }
    }
}


public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Vertex v0 = new Vertex("Nottinghill_Gate");
Vertex v1 = new Vertex("High_Street_kensignton");
Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Glouchester_Road");
Vertex v3 = new Vertex("South_Kensignton");
Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Sloane_Square");
Vertex v5 = new Vertex("Victoria");
Vertex v6 = new Vertex("Westminster");
v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v1,  79.83), new Edge(v6,  97.24)};
v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v2,  39.42), new Edge(v0, 79.83)};
v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v3,  38.65), new Edge(v1, 39.42)};
v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v4, 102.53), new Edge(v2,  38.65)};
v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v5, 133.04), new Edge(v3, 102.53)};
v5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v6,  81.77), new Edge(v4, 133.04)};
v6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,  97.24), new Edge(v5, 81.77)};
Vertex[] vertices = { v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 };


    computePaths(v0);
    for (Vertex v : vertices)
{
    System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
    List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
    System.out.println("Path: " + path);
}

}
}
```

The code is based on http://en.literateprograms.org/Special:Downloadcode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29 [last accessed on 6th January 2011]

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend describing your graph in [Trivial Graph Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Graph_Format).

This is what it will look like:

```
v0 Harrisburg
v1 Baltimore
v2 Washington
v3 Philadelphia
v4 Binghamton
v5 Allentown
v6 New York
#
v0 v1 79.83
v0 v5 81.15
v1 v0 79.75
v1 v2 39.42
v1 v3 103.00
v2 v1 38.65
v3 v1 102.53
v3 v5 61.44
v3 v6 96.79
v4 v5 133.04
v5 v0 81.77
v5 v3 62.05
v5 v4 134.47
v5 v6 91.63
v6 v3 97.24
v6 v5 87.94
```

You can then parse this file and create the Vertex and Edge objects.

Here is the complete code:

```
class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
    public final String name;
    public List<Edge> adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) {
        name = argName;
        adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        adjacencies.add(e);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}

class Edge {
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) {
        target = argTarget;
        weight = argWeight;
    }
}


public class Dijkstra {

    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u

            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);
                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<String, Vertex> vertexMap = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("graph.txt"));
            String line;
            boolean inVertex = true;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.charAt(0) == '#') {
                    inVertex = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (inVertex) {
                    //store the vertices
                    int indexOfSpace = line.indexOf(' ');
                    String vertexId = line.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
                    String vertexName = line.substring(indexOfSpace + 1);
                    Vertex v = new Vertex(vertexName);
                    vertexMap.put(vertexId, v);
                } else {
                    //store the edges
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    String vFrom = parts[0];
                    String vTo = parts[1];
                    double weight = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
                    Vertex v = vertexMap.get(vFrom);
                    if (v != null) {
                        v.addEdge(new Edge(vertexMap.get(vTo), weight));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally{
            if(in!= null)
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
        }

        //get a list of all the vertices
        Collection<Vertex> vertices = vertexMap.values();
        Vertex source = vertices.iterator().next();
        System.out.println("Computing paths from " + source);
        computePaths(source);
        for (Vertex v : vertices) {
            System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can store the data in the text file in a methodical manner, such as leave a space between every other data. Thereafter you can use the Java File Reader and read the contents of that file into an array. Once its in the array you can pass the array index into the respective places where the data has to be added in your code. 
For example it would look similar to this, (here the String type array as is used to store the data from the text file. Therefore you can use its indexes to add the data to your code.

```
FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream("FileName.txt");
DataInputStream datainputstream = new DataInputStream(fileinputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(datainputstream));                                    
do{
   String s1;
   if((s1 = bufferedreader1.readLine()) == null){
       break;
  }
       String as[] = s1.split(" "); 
} while(true);
   datainputstream.close(); 
}
```